# Multiprocessing Pool Hangs After Processing (on close or join)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

My main method (which is properly protected from being run when importing) looks like this:

```
def main():
    json_file, csv_out = get_user_input()
    sessions = get_sessions(json_file)

    if sessions:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        pool.map_async(process_one_item, sessions, 1)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    write_csv(csv_out, json_file, sessions)
```

It processes every single session (of over 1,000), which is just a list of timestamps that get processed before being written to disk, but when it finishes the final one, it just hangs. It never gets to "write_csv," which reads what has been written to disk.

What am I missing?

Update 1:

```
def main():
    json_file, csv_out = get_user_input()
    sessions = get_sessions(json_file)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    for results in pool.imap_unordered(func=process_one_item, 
                                       iterable=sessions, chunksize=1):
        store_results(results)

    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()

    write_csv(csv_out, json_file, sessions)
```

This also hung.

The program can run if given less than 200 items AND finish. But when I go over 1,000, it hangs...

Update 2:

I added some print statements so I could better tell where it hangs.

```
def main():
    json_file, csv_out = get_user_input()
    sessions = get_sessions(json_file)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    for results in pool.imap_unordered(func=process_one_item, 
                                       iterable=sessions):
        store_results(results)
        print('...now back to main')

    print('Terminate NOW.')
    pool.terminate()
    print('Join NOW.')
    pool.join()

write_csv(csv_out, json_file, sessions)
```

"...now back to main" always prints.

"Terminate NOW." never prints.

Update 3:

Here's the stacktrace from when it's hanging and I kill the run.

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-13:
Process ForkPoolWorker-23:
Process ForkPoolWorker-29:
Process ForkPoolWorker-27:
Process ForkPoolWorker-30:
Process ForkPoolWorker-31:
Process ForkPoolWorker-26:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 759, in next
    item = self._items.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 214, in main
    for results in pool.imap_unordered(func=process_one_item, iterable=sessions):
  File , line 763, in next
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File ", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 352, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File , line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File , line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File , line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
    self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File , line 296, in wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File , line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File , line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File , line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File , line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've removed the filenames to protect the innocent (user name in the path).

Update 4:

I added faulthandling and set a timeout.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    faulthandler.enable()
    faulthandler.dump_traceback_later(timeout=60, repeat=True, exit=True)
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    print('\nDone!\n\nThis code ran in {:.1f} seconds'.format(time.perf_counter()-start_time))
```

When I did this I got a timeout and a stack trace of:

```
Thread 0x00001094 (most recent call first):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 306 in _recv_bytes  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250 in recv  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 489 in _handle_results  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrapThread 0x0000476c (most recent call first):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 284 in _send_bytes  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206 in send  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 450 in _handle_tasks  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrapThread 0x00002d80 (most recent call first):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 432 in _handle_workers  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrapThread 0x000038a8 (most recent call first):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 750 in next  File "C:/Users/mtanner/IdeaProjects/cti_trending_analysis/main.py", line 215 in main  File "C:/Users/mtanner/IdeaProjects/cti_trending_analysis/main.py", line 231 in <module>Process SpawnPoolWorker-36:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closedDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 130, in worker    put((job, i, (False, wrapped)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closedProcess SpawnPoolWorker-28:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closedDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 130, in worker    put((job, i, (False, wrapped)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closedProcess SpawnPoolWorker-26:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closedDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 130, in worker    put((job, i, (False, wrapped)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 344, in put    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Update 5:

In my function `process_one_item` function, I used the `sys.exit(-1)` call, attempting to end the run when something code-breaking happened. (this program was originally not multiprocessed). I think the multiprocessing was hiding this effect. I removed this call and the program now runs to completion regardless of session count.

If someone can explain all this, I'm happy to count that as the solution!

Comment: I am also having the same issue, though my code never uses `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: What about to change chunksize?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the code to test this anymore :(